# How to access external database from android using Rest webservice without using php

Tags: android

I want to connect to oracle database from android simple login I want use only Rest web service Json . I dont want to use PHP.

How can i do that Please give more examples!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In android, the latest way of making a network call is by using google's own volley library. But you will have to make a web service using PHP/Java and the easiest way to make a web service is by using PHP.

In your android studio you will just use the volley library and make a call to the webservice which will intern fetch data from the database and send you the response in the form of a JSON or your custom model class.

Below are the links that might help you:

1. [Using PHP](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)
2. [Using JAVA](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-create-restful-webservice-in-java-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks Kaveesh. I will try to implement using java

Comment: Please can you do a example

Comment: I have done it in the same way as it is shown in the "Using PHP" link of my answer. It is very simple. Try it once and tell me where you are finding it difficult to understand the code. Also, you should have some basic knowledge of xampp or wampp control and mysql db. If you do not have xampp download it from  [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

To use the database you have to use the Web service, otherwise the security of your database will be lost. [Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/web-services-tutorial) you can learn about web services in Java

Answer (score 0):

I you wanna use AspNet, then I suggest you use AspNet Web API (samples can be found at [Asp Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)) for server-side.

Android login sample: refer my answer at [How to use security (Authentication & Authorization) in ASP Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466653/how-to-use-security-authentication-authorization-in-asp-web-api/31471027#31471027)

Hope this help!