# Authentication Android with token

Tags: android

I read a lot of things about authentication, but I don't know what's the best way to proceed.

How to create a token ? Should I use OAuth2 ?
Can I store this token in SharedPreference to keep session alive when the user closes/reopens the app and when he uses the app ? Is it secured ?

I'm a bit lost.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is a good idea to store token instead of passwords and usernames. So you can authenticate against a system and do that things you need to do. For more background why storing passwords is a bad idea: Passwords are often used on multiple platforms so if an attacker get one password the user has a big damage, while token expire and can been renewed often without any user interaction.

Typically you get tokens with OAuth sometimes also with a initial credentials authentification. In the end you have a token which you to send to each request so the server will know who you are.

You can safely store those tokens. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> How to create a token ?

About this, you can refer to my answer at [How to use security (Authentication & Authorization) in ASP Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466653/how-to-use-security-authentication-authorization-in-asp-web-api/31471027#31471027)

Sample code for getting access token from remote web service (for example, Asp.Net Web API):

```
public static Object getAccessToken(String address, String grant_type, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grant_type));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // Making HTTP request
    httpResponse = makeHTTPRequest(address, params);
    if (httpResponse != null) {
        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK && statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
            return httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        }

        // Get JSON String (jsonString) from Input Stream (is)
        getJSONFromInputStream();
        if (jsonString.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        // Parse the JSON String to a JSON Object
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    }

    return jObj;
}
```

Inside makeHTTPRequest, for request access token:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
```

Hope this provides you with some information you need.

Comment: Thanks everyone, very usefull, sorry I can't upvote :/

Answer (score 1):

Let the user enter his username and password. Send them to your server using HTTP, I use volley library for such things, generate '**token**', '**time of generation**'  and '**time to live**' in server and send them to the app as a response. In the app ,store all in shared preferences.

Now, every time you want to communicate with the server get actual time and subtract from it the time of generation, if result is smaller than your time to live, do communication, otherwise it means the **token** is dead, request from the user to login another time and request a new token.